# Superset Time Series Bar Chart: How to Order metrics as they appear in the metrics box

Tags: apache-superset

I have a time-series bar chart with 3 metrics - Time to A, Time to B and Time to C in this order but Superset reorders them - Time to B, Time to C and Time to A as shown in the picture below.

I looked around but couldn't find a way to correct this ordering issue.

[image]

Comment: This is a good feature request, do you mind creating a ticket on Github asking for it?